Учебник по Delphi в 2024
Какой учебник, на 2024 год, остается актуальным или является актуальным. Цель изучить язык, его стандартную библиотеку, увидеть практическое использование. Разобраться как писать программы кросс-платформенные графические и с учетом актуальности на 2024 год
Как писать библиотеки для этого языка на других языках или где искать

для знающих ответ: лучше внести его в описание метки

Интересно, реально дельфи всё ещё используют в программировании?)) Я думал он устарел лет 10 назад и умер))

@АлексейШиманский сотни вакансий по Европе кстати.

Лучше уж тогда c# учить.

@АлексейШиманский лет 10 назад в него очень много плюшек с точки зрения самого языка добавили

по сабжу мануал по самому языку в документации весьма хорош. Прям если хотите разобраться в синтаксисе и возможностях читайте его, единственное прочитать надо дважды-трижды, с каждым разом появляется новый взгляд.
Из литературы - Марко Канту раньше хорошие книги писал, которые думаю актуальны и сейчас.

@АлексейШиманский В ряде стран Европы, после Голландского скандала, Delphi - один из немногих языков, разрешенных для написания программ обработки данных больных. Сам часто пишу на Delphi, оптимизация по скорости, к примеру, под Ryzen'ы там великолепна

@ViktorTomilov подскажите пожалуйста, как загуглить? Не слышал про такое дело

@Kromster Ищите именно Голландский скандал (Dutch syndrome). Из первых рук не знаю, увы, периодически поднимается в кулуарах на конференциях. Речь о том, что при использовании нестрогих к синтаксису препроцессоров была допущена существенная ошибка при обработке данных, которая повлияла на лечение. Разные слухи говорят о разном количестве пострадавших.

Вам предстоит вечно сражаться с сайтами тестирующими ПО. Например всем известный Virus Total - что-нибудь, да найдёт (в любой программе скомпилированной старыми компиляторами).

Недавно вот на форумах абра-кадабры (Embracadero) активно обсуждалась вот эта книженция.
https://lp.embarcadero.com/CodinginDelphi
Туфта полная, но в ней есть пару глав по новым фишкам в новых Delphi.
https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/object-pascal-handbook
Библия FMX программиста.
https://www.amazon.com/Delphi-GUI-Programming-FireMonkey-interfaces/dp/1788624173
Оч крутая по Delphi + Работа с базами (Есть русская версия)
https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Delphi-Developers-Guide-Ado/dp/1556227582
Оч старая, бородатая книга. Но читается прям с запоем.
https://www.rulit.me/books/delphi-v-shutku-i-vserez-chto-umeyut-hakery-download-412521.html
В дополнение к комментариям.

Нет, Delphi не умер. Он отлично расцветает в своей сфере - Медицина, Нефтегазодобыча, Логистика, Наука.
Вакансий много, хороших работников мало. Как в принципе везде в IT.
Основной источник знаний - официальная документация. Слава богу Delphi отлично документирован со стороны разработчиков.
Так-же отличный источник знаний это коллеги. Думаю что поработать годика 2-3 в компании на ставке джуна будет куда практичнее сотни книг.
C# не лучше учить, в указанные мной сферы этому языку не прорваться от слова совсем. Как правило на Delphi пишут взрослые дяди за 30 в таком окружении, тебя просто не поймут.

От себя добавлю
Pascal в принципе очень старый язык. Приходиться очень много писать, как правило того что даже писать не хочется. В профессиональной сфере в компаниях не допускается даже использование сторонних компонентов. Очень часто хочется всё бросить и взять что попроще где из коробки уже всё готовое за тебя написали. Но с другой стороны как раз в сфере именно Delphi программистов можно точно не бояться что тебя заменит шальной студент или ChatGPT. Это монотонная стабильная работа, где над одним проектом можно работать по 5 лет и не волноваться за завтрашний день.
